# Issue with Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to use leave one out cross validation. But i am getting below error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-f15f1e522706> in <module>()
      3 loo = LeaveOneOut(num_of_examples)
      4 #loo.get_n_splits(X_train_std)
----> 5 for train, test in loo.split(X_train_std):
      6     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
```

AttributeError: 'LeaveOneOut' object has no attribute 'split'

The detailed code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut
num_of_examples = len(X_train_std)
loo = LeaveOneOut(num_of_examples)
for train, test in loo.split(X_train_std):
print("%s %s" % (train, test))
```

Comment: from the doc (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) it looks like you need to split your set first using `loo.get_n_splits(X_train)`

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: This is impossible to read. Please edit your original question and include the complete error message into it.

Comment: @DYZ i modified my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using scikit-learn version below 0.18 and maybe referring some tutorials for version 0.18.

In versions prior to 0.18, the `LeaveOneOut()` constructor has a required parameter `n` which is not supplied in the above code you posted. Hence the error. You can refer to the [documentation of LeaveOneOut for version 0.17 here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut) where its mentioned that:

> Parameters:    **n** : int Total number of elements in dataset.

Solution:

- Update the scikit-learn to version 0.18
- Initialize the **LeaveOneOut** as follows:

  `loo = LeaveOneOut(size of X_train_std)`

**Edit**:

If you are using the scikit version >=0.18:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    print("%s %s" % (train_index, test_index))
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Else, for versions < 0.18 use the iterations like this (Notice that here `loo.split()` is not used, `loo` is used directly):

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut
loo = LeaveOneOut(num_of_examples)
for train_index, test_index in loo:
    print("%s %s" % (train_index, test_index))
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: i have made the necessary changes to remove previous error but i do have another error which i don't know how i can solve it. I have modified my initial code again

Comment: @Shelly What version of scikit are you using?. I have edited the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Kumer if i use this: from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut    I would get this error: ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.model_selection' which refers to my scikit version is not above 0.18. and the error in my initial code is not because of using" from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut"

Comment: @Shelly Ok. I have edited the answer to reflect the changes

Comment: Even this change can not make the code right. I am getting error again:  NameError                                 
     11 loo = LeaveOneOut(num_of_examples)
     12 for train_index, test_index in loo:
---> 13     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
     14 

NameError: name 'train' is not defined

Comment: @Shelly Change train to train_index, test to test_index

Comment: @Shelly I have updated my answer to remove that error. You need to understand that `loo` or `loo.split(X)` will return the index of splitting. You then need to slice your `X` and `y` arrays according to those indices to get the train and test arrays. Replace X, y with your features and labels arrays.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

rather than cross_validation because cross_validation in changed into model_selction

Comment: Please explain your answer with more details and write it in a better readable format.