# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits' ERROR

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was going to try the code in this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py):

I am getting error from the line which refers to `StratifiedKFold(n_splits=60)`. Can anybody tell me how i can solve this error?

Here is the Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y
X, y

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

mean_tpr = 0.0
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-2af2773f4987> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
      2 #cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6,  shuffle=True, random_state=1)
      3 classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
      4                      random_state=random_state)
      5 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'
```

Comment: `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold` is not `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold` and does not take the same arguments.

Comment: In the link they have used `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`. But you are using `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold`. The module `cross_validation` has been deprecated. I'm sure that you must have gotten a warning for it.

Comment: @Vivek The reason i am using sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold is that i am getting error when using sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold. I haven't got any warning when using **sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold**

Comment: @Shelly I have answered your problem. But one more thing I noticed is that you just hit and run. ie ask questions, comment on answers if it doesnt solve, then nothing. Neither do you accept the answers which solve the problem, nor does you even comment that your problem has been solved by a specific answer or not.

Answer (score 5):

You are not getting any warnings while importing the `sklearn.cross-validation` module. This means that your installed version is less than 0.18.

If your scikit-learn version is `< 0.18`, then change the below lines:
(Taken from [StratifiedKFold documentation for version 0.17](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold))

```
#Notice the extra parameter y and change of name for n_splits to n_folds
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=6)

#Also note that the cv is called directly in for loop
for train_index, test_index in cv:
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

If your scikit-learn version is `>=0.18`, then only you can use the `n_splits` parameter for the `cv`:
(Taken from [StratifiedKFold current documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), which is what I think you are referring to)

```
#Notice the extra parameter y is removed here
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)

#Also note that the cv.split() is called here (opposed to cv in ver 0.17 above)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X, y):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

**Recommendation**:

Update your scikit-learn to the latest version 0.18. Because most documentation you will find by directly searching will be of this version and it will get you confused.

Edit:

I have already answered your similar question here:
- [Issue with Cross Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175059/issue-with-cross-validation)

So next time, please mention the version of libraries you use in the question itself, and remember to access their relevant documentation, not the other ones.